# Find the symmetric difference of two finite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Find the symmetric difference, $A \triangle B$, where $A=\{6,7,8,9,10\}$, and
$B$ is the set of *odd* integers between $5$ and $10$. The end points are exclusive.

I think the only answer it could be is $10$. If it is not can someone point me into the right direction?

Comment: Note that the members of $B$ are odd, so for instance $6$ is not in $B$, so it must be in the symmetric difference.

Comment: i completely overlooked that.

Answer (score 1):

$A\Delta B = (A -B)\cup(B-A)=(A-B)\cup \emptyset=A-B=\{6,8,10\}$

> For "$A\Delta B = (A -B)\cup(B-A)$", see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454020/show-that-symmetric-difference-is-a-delta-b-a-cup-b-a-cap-b).

Answer (score 0):

The symmetric difference $A \Delta B$ is defined as 
$$ A \Delta B := (A \cup B) \backslash (A \cap B) \; .$$

We have $A = \{6,7,8,9,10\}$ and $B = \{7,9\}$. Now it sould not be difficult to calculate the symmetric difference. Write down what $A \cup B$ and $A \cap B$ is, and you will easily see the result of $A \Delta B$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at it if you like is: note that $B\subseteq A$, then $A\cup B=A$ and $A\cap B = B$, so $$A\Delta B = (A\cup B)-(A\cap B)=A-B$$ which gives you a more general trick.