# Prove $\neg(A ▲ B) = (A ∩ B) ∪ (\neg(A) ∩ \neg(B))$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

$A\Delta B= (A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$

Let $x$ be in $not(A \Delta  B)$. Then $x$ cannot be in A \Delta B, meaning it cannot be in $(A\setminus B) ∪ (B\setminus A)$. So $x$ is not in $A\setminus B$ and it is not in $B\setminus A$. Therefore $x$ must be in either $A ∩ B$ or $(\neg(A) ∩ \neg(B))$.

So $x$ is in $(A ∩ B)$ ∪ $(\neg(A) ∩ \neg(B))$, meaning
 $\neg(A \Delta B) = (A ∩ B) ∪ (\neg(A) ∩ \neg(B))$.

Is this a correct proof?

Answer (score 1):

You correctly proved one direction ($\subseteq$), and you should prove the other direction too. I give another proof, maybe a help.

$(A\Delta B)^c= [(A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)]^c= [(A\cup B)\cap (A\cap B)^c]^c=(A\cup B)^c \cup (A\cap B)$$
= (A^c\cap B^c) \cup (A\cap B).$

Here I used [another definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454020/show-that-symmetric-difference-is-a-delta-b-a-cup-b-a-cap-b) of $A\Delta B$ which is equivalent with yours. I also used [*De Morgan's laws*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) at 3rd and 4th step. I also used the formula: $X\setminus Y=X\cap Y^c$

---

> using another def. of $\Delta$: $(A\Delta B)^c= [(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)]^c=[(A\cap B^c)\cup(B\cap A^c)]^c =(A\cap B^c)^c\cap(B\cap A^c)^c=(A^c\cup B)\cap (B^c\cup A) =[(A\cap B) \cup A^c]\cap [(A\cap B) \cup B^c]=(A\cap B) \cup (A^c\cap B^c)$